# Existing TLS/SSL connection stops after some time when removing certificate

Tags: c#, ssl, tcp, certificate, tls1.2

I've two machine: A and B.

In machine A I've a c# application that sends data to the B machine over TLS connection using certificate that was brought from machine B and added to machine A trusted root certification.

As long as the certificate exists in machine A the data from A to B goes successfully and the connection continues. On the other hand, if I remove the certificate while A is sending data to B, then after some time the connection resets and stops.

What I'm trying to understand is what causes the connection to stop because it doesn't happen immediately or after a fixed time, but seems randomly, sometimes the connection keeps for few minutes and sometimes for an hour and more.

Notice that the connections stops whether its idle or not, after random time from the time the certificate was removed.

What exactly triggers the connection reset after the certificate is removed?

Comment: [ServicePointManager](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.servicepointmanager)  -> [ServicePoint](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.servicepoint) -> [ServicePointManager.MaxServicePointIdleTime](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.servicepointmanager.maxservicepointidletime)

Comment: @Jimi I've updated the question, but it should not be related to idle time because it also happens in fully active time.

Comment: Reaching the default idle timeout (when the connection is dropped and, possibly, a few seconds later - or less- another is requested) is one possible reason. A redirection can trigger a handshake, a change in protocol, a Load Balancer etc.

Answer (score 0):

- Ideally the certificate will be exchanged during the time of handshake.
- The connection retry or reset can happen if you redirect to diff    connections.
- Try to get a pcap during the message transfer in any of the machine and check what was the last message sent before the connection drop, whether its graceful or abrupt disconnect.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34849934)